# How do I get only node IDs from the search results?

Tags: 7, search

I'm using Search API Solr with custom searches in code, but I want to find a way to limit the return results to only the nid to save on bandwidth with our third-party solr server. I've tried $query->fields(array('nid')) but I receive the following error.

> SearchApiException: Trying to search on field nid which is no indexed fulltext field.

I am using the following code (simplified).

```
$index = search_api_index_load('my_index');
$query = $index->query();
$query->keys($search_terms);
$query->fields(array('nid')); // doesn't work
$results = $query->execute();
return $results;
```

How do I get only node IDs from `$results`?

Answer (score 1):

As @AjitS mentions, if the original node ID is not indexed, then you can't retrieve it from the fields of the search results.

The annoying thing is that the search API knows the IDs, but they're not in an easy to use form. It's happy to give you a list of `entity:node/1:en` type references, which you can decompose into the original node IDs with something cheesy like this:

```
  # Converts a list of "entity:node/1:en" type strings to a list of integers
  public function get_nids_from_search_ids($ids) {
    $nids = [];
    foreach($ids as $id) {
      if(substr($id, 0, 12) == 'entity:node/') {
        $rest = substr($id, 12);
        $pieces = explode(':', $rest);
        if($pieces[0] != "") {
          array_push($nids, $pieces[0]);
        }
      }
    }
    return $nids;
  }
```

It feels like there ought to be a better way *without* needing to additionally index the node IDs, but it seems there isn't. I guess one day the search API may include convenience methods to get (rigorously) at the "parts" of the IDs it returns.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `fields()` method of the `SearchAPIQuery` class makes the search in fields with datatype `fulltext`.

In order to get the `nid` in the result, you have to ensure that its value is being indexed by search_api. You can check that at `/admin/config/search/search_api/index/my_index/fields` (`my_index` is the name of the index in this case).

To filter using the nid field you might have to use the `condition` method instead. The following should work:

```
$index = search_api_index_load('my_index');
$query = $index->query();
$query->keys($search_terms);
$query->condition('nid', $val); // The third parameter "operator" defaults to "="
$results = $query->execute();
return $results;
```

Comment: To clarify I don't want to filter by nid (I'm actually using lots of filters already), I only want to return the nids - I don't need all the extra fields as I'm doing a node_load on them afterwards.

Comment: @Chris `nid`s are returned by the search_api when they are indexed (first part of the answer). Can you make sure that it is being indexed?